# Error defining a string array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I am trying to define a a string array in MATLAB but due to unknown reasons I am getting an error 
the syntax I used for creating a string array is

```
label_unit = ['Time'; 'FT'; 'Normalized' ;'Quantized'; 'Encoded']
```

and I get an error that 
'Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.'
although I am not concatenating any matrices
the problem is when I use MATLABs own definition of a string which was

```
S = ['abc ';'defg';'hi  ']
```

source :http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html

I do not get any error but the moment I replace my string in the above matrix I get the same error

Comment: As @AlexanderBüse points out you should use cell arrays instead.

Comment: You *are* concatenating matrices. To MATLAB, a `character` array is a matrix of characters. `A = [0 1; 0];` also does not work, which is essentially what you are attempting to do with `label_unit`.

Comment: @excaza but the array defined by MATLAB is working

Comment: @MatthiasW.I tried using cell array but when i write to an excel file in the end it write the whole cell to just one cell of the excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

```
cols = {'A', 'B', 'C'}

a = {'a1';'a2';'a3'};

b = {'b1';'b2';'b3'};

c = {'1';'2';'3'};

xlswrite('test.xls', [cols,; a,b,c]);
```

writes "test.xls" in current directorym with the content of:

```
A   B   C

a1  b1  c1

a2  b2  c2

a3  b3  c3
```